# AWS MediaLive with PHP SDK not return channel lists

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I try to use AWS SDK for PHP with MediaLive service. I just wonder if aws-cli command is work fine

```
aws medialive list-channels
```

Below code is return result, but "Channels" not return channel lists. What's wrong?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Aws\MediaLive\MediaLiveClient   ([
    'version'     => '2017-10-14',
    'region'      => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'debug'   => false,
    'validate' => true,
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '<MYKEY>',
        'secret' => '<MYSECRET>'
    ],
]);

$result = $client->listChannels();
print_r($result);
```

?>

Thank you.

Comment: same problem did you find a fix?

Comment: Make sure the region is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$MediaLiveClient = new MediaLiveClient([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '<MYKEY>',
            'secret' => '<MYSECRET>'
        ]
    ]);

$ListChannels = $MediaLiveClient->getPaginator('ListChannels');
$ChannelsArray = [];

    foreach($ListChannels as $Result){
        if (count($Result->get('Channels')) > 0){
            foreach($Result->get('Channels') as $key => $value){
                array_push($ChannelsArray, $value);
            }
        }
    }
print_r($ChannelsArray);
```